# WPF Line position in ItemsControl is off

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to draw lines on canvas using `ItemsControl`. I'm using MVVM architecture. I'm having a problem that every line is drawn at {0, 0} coordinates despite the start/end position binding (I double checked, the values are correct).

```
<ItemsControl Name="ic2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Edges}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="{Binding X}"
                  Y1="{Binding Y}"
                  X2="{Binding DestinationX}"
                  Y2="{Binding DestinationY}"
                  Panel.ZIndex="10"
                  StrokeThickness="5"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  Stretch="Fill"
                  Fill="Black" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I'm setting DataContex of ItemsControl (ic2) in MainWindow `this.ic2.DataContext = new MapManagerVM();`

MVVM class `MapManagerVM` contains

```
public ObservableCollection<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
```

Class `Edge` contains `int` property for `X`, `Y`, `DestinationX` and `DestinationY`.

Referring to the picture below, the black line should be between blue nodes. As you can see, length of the line is correct, but the position is off (object's `X` and `Y` are correct but they are incorrectly painted on canvas)
[image: Wrong line position]

Comment: Do not set `Stretch="Fill"`. It's obviously not what you want. Setting `Panel.ZIndex="10"` also doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: My idea behind the ZIndex was that I want the line below the nodes (not above them as seen on the picture)

Comment: You're right! That fixed my issue! Thank you so much! (The position was still off but I managed to fix that by offseting the coordinates).

Comment: I guess the nodes are in a different ItemsControl and hence in a different Canvas. ZIndex however has an effect only on child elements of the same Canvas. For the placement of the nodes, apparently they are aligned at their top left corner, but you want them centered. Instead of an Ellipse you should use a Path with an EllipseGeometry.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are correct, I'll try to put them into the same canvas. As for a centering the ellipses, I'm setting top left corner and for the rest, I'm calculating the center via the size. I'll take a loot on EllipseGeometry. Thank you for a tip and solving my problem. Do you wanna put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42246896/1136211. For the ZIndex, just put the lines ItemsControl below the nodes ItemsControl.