How to plot more than 40000 points in ScottPlot
I need to plot 5,000 circles using ScottPlot, but I'm experiencing lag every time I move the mouse on the screen. I was able to easily use Scatter for points, but how can I solve this for circles?
Should I use a different library instead of ScottPlot.WPF?
double[] xData = chart.MeasuredData[i].XAxis.ToArray();
double[] yData = chart.MeasuredData[i].YAxis.ToArray();

// Ellipse
for (int data = 0; data < xData.Length; data++)
{
    wpfPlotGL.Plot.Add.Ellipse(xData[data], yData[data], 2.9, 2.9);
}
wpfPlotGL.Refresh();

I'll edit it. It wasn't 4000 circles, it was 40000 circles.

If you are experiencing lag during the mouse movement, i assume you are using WPF/Xaml rendering and you most likely you have connected events to your ellipse (mouse over as for example for detailed tooltip, or it is in the subsystem of the ScottPlot). also give a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952657/most-performant-way-to-graph-thousands-of-data-points-with-wpf

I need to be able to move, enlarge, and reduce the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Thats the "canvas" interaction and not nodes themselves. This should be possible without a lag. I am not familiar with the library and docs are a bit limited, so it's difficult for me to say where the bottlenecks are. I know I spend lot of time optimizing Telerik library for plotting and it works well with larger scaled datasets. you can try https://livecharts.dev/ since its free and see if you have any better performance (sorry for not being too helpful on the topic)

If it's actually using "Ellipses" for circles, then those are "UIElements" that are orders of magnitude more resource demanding than "points" or lines (i.e. pixels).

I think drawing 40,000 circles would be detrimental to performance, so after a meeting, we decided to apply a filter for drawing. Thank you for your help.
